# How to change assembly info in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-assembly, auto-versioning, assembly-attributes

I want to versioning my asp.net core app.

I followed this link: http://www.matthiaseinig.de/2013/05/20/auto-generate-fileversion-for-all-projects-in-a-solution-with-t4/ , but I want to remove project assembly info, but I didn't find it.

How to remove duplicated assembly info? I want to override asp core assemblies with another file.

[image]
[image]
[image]


**BETTER SOLUTION**

After a while I realize that the best solution is to use a T4 file, the version is incremented automatically after each build.

look here:

http://www.matthiaseinig.de/2013/05/20/auto-generate-fileversion-for-all-projects-in-a-solution-with-t4/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Right now properties could be defined in `.csproj` or using `AssemblyInfo.cs`, but only the one place could be used, otherwise "Duplicate" errors are generated.

---

If you want to use `AssemblyInfo.cs`, add the following into `.csproj` to avoid duplication errors:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you are interesting how does it work, look into [GenerateAssemblyInfo task](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets).

---

Otherwise, remove `AssemblyInfo.cs` and add the following property into your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblyVersion>1.2.3.4</AssemblyVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```