# How can you share Assembly Info between VS 2019-formatted projects?

Tags: versioning, visual-studio-2019, assemblyinfo, projects-and-solutions

In VS 2017, or more accurately, the old project format used in VS 2017, each project had a 'Properties' folder with an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file which held things like project version, copyright, etc.

If you wanted to share some of that information between several projects, say all those in a particular solution, you created a `AssemblyInfo_Shared.cs` file, moved the shared properties into it, removing them from the original `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, then you would 'link' the shared version into each separate project.

Now when you build, information that is in `AssemblyInfo_Shared.cs` will be shared between all projects where as project-specific values would remain in the original `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

However, in the new project format, these values are all embedded into the project's file, which now is a simple XML file.  How can you share settings between projects now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change assembly info in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727007/how-to-change-assembly-info-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: See linked question: the answer shows a change to the `csproj` file that reverts to the previous behaviour of having explicit assembly level attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties (and even items) in the project file are processed by MSBuild, and can easily be refactored into `.props` and `.targets` files that are shared among your projects.

With the new project file format, MSBuild will automatically import files named `Directory.Build.props` at the beginning of your project, and `Directory.Build.targets` at the end - this includes searching up the folder tree until one of these is found.  With this, it is very easy to share properties across all projects in your solution: simply create a `Directory.Build.props` file in the solution folder with your version properties, and every project will share those properties.

Comment: This looks promising, but how does it know when to stop searching up the tree?  Also, is this related to the `<import />` tag?  I saw MSBuild references to that and tried to use it, and while it did work, VS shows an error banner (but again, it did work!)

Comment: The search for Directory.Build.* goes up the directory path until it finds one.  It's also conditional so that it doesn't fail if it doesn't find a match.  And yes, it's done with an `<Import />`.  I can't speak to the VS error without knowing more.